# Instantiate FeatureLayer without using require statement ArcGIS javascript api 4.x

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Using ArcGIS javascript api 4.x, what is the correct way to instantiate a FeatureLayer without using the require statement?  For example, If I want to create a query object, I can instantiate it using the require statement as follows:

```
require([
"esri/tasks/support/Query"
],
function (Query) {
var query = new Query();
});
```

But I can also instantiate it without the require statement as follows:

```
var query = myLayer.createQuery();
```

Now if I want to instantiate a FeatureLayer using the require statement I can do so as follows:

```
require([
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
],
function (FeatureLayer) {
var myLayer = new FeatureLayer();
});
```

Now the question is, how can I instantiate a FeatureLayer without the require statement?

Thank you.

**SOLUTION**

Solution provided by cabesuon.  Using the query object instead of a featurelayer resolved the issue.  I am able to reuse the query object with no need to instantiate.

More info

[esri-rest-query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-rest-query.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that, you need to import `FeatureLayer` to use it.

The case you mention with `Query` is different. In it, `FeatureLayer` is importing `Query` "for you" and offer a way for using it. It works as a proxy for creating `Query` objects.

If, just as an example, `Map` had a method for creating `FeatureLayer` objects, then you could avoid the import sentence.

Now, `FeatureLayer` offers a method to create a `Query` object because is handy, this method preset properties related to the service witch in other way you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you Cabesuon!  Basically, the problem is, I am re-using FeatureLayer (adding new features) and need to remove all the existing features, the source and the url also needs to be reset.  And I need to do this outside of the "require" area.  Basically I need the FeatureLayer to be as if I had just instantiated it.  Is there a way to "reset" that object?  I tried myLayer.destroy() (fails), myLayer.clear() (fails) and myLayer.initilize (fails).

Comment: Usually, you do not reset the remote source of a layer, if you have more than one source you just create a new one. Remove the layer from the map, create a new one and add it to the map. As for "outside of the request", you need to provide more context on the structure of your app, but there is always a way to do it.

Comment: Thank you.  The reason is that it is a "Temporary" FeatureLayer that returns the results of a Query.  If I dont instatiate it, the second time I use it, the Query does not return the correct information.  I was able to resolve the issue using require...new FeatureLayer every time I create a new query but it is very ugly.  I was just wondering if there was a way I can reset the FeatureLayer without having the have the require...new FeatureLayer... in the middle of the code.  Something like myLayer.reset().

Comment: That is not necessary wrong, create a `FeatureLayer` for every source you need to show and/or updates features. How many sources do you have?. BTW, you do not need to use a `FeatureLayer` to query a feature source, you can just use `query` ([ArcGIS JS API - ESRI rest query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-rest-query.html)).

Comment: Thank you again Cabesuon!  Using the query object from the link you mentioned resolved the issue!

Comment: Hi Cabesuon, by any chance do you know about basemapToggle.  I have a new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76465001

Comment: I post a possible answer, take a look