# How to change one of the basemaps on a BasemapToggle widget using arcgis js api 4

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have created a BaseMapToggle control using arcgis javascript api 4

```
require([
"esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
...


basemapToggle = new BasemapToggle({
view: view,
nextBasemap: map2
});
```

I tried the following:

```
// Change Map
basemapToggle.activeBasemap = map3;
```

I only need two maps, but I need to change the second map to a new value.

But it does not change the current map.  What would be the correct way to change one of the two maps on a BasemapToggle widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I think that the `BasemapToggle` ([ArcGIS API - BasemapToggle](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-BasemapToggle.html)) widget was not created with the idea of being able to switch the options, just because it does not seem to give an option for it. If you have several basemaps, I think that you should try `BasemapGallery` widget ([ArcGIS API - BasemapGallery](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-BasemapGallery.html)).</del>

<del>Anyway, if you still want to use `BasemapToggle`, you can always recreate the widget any time you need. Take a look at the example I made for the case.</del>

Well, I was wrong, and I overcomplicate it. You just need to reset `nextBasemap` property.

Here is the re-work example,

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>
      Intro to widgets using BasemapToggle | Sample | ArcGIS Maps SDK for
      JavaScript 4.27
    </title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/"></script>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle"
      ], (Map, MapView, BasemapToggle) => {
        let basemap = "topo-vector";
        let nextBasemap = "hybrid";

        const map = new Map({
          basemap
        });
        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          center: [-86.049, 38.485],
          zoom: 3
        });
        const toggle = new BasemapToggle({
            view: view,
            nextBasemap
        });
        view.ui.add(toggle, "top-right");
        toggle.watch('activeBasemap', function (newBasemap) {
            let temp = basemap;
            basemap = nextBasemap;
            nextBasemap = temp;
            temp = basemapButton;
            basemapButton = nextBasemapButton;
            nextBasemapButton = temp;
        });

        const bTopoVector = document.getElementById("bTopoVector");
        const bHybrid = document.getElementById("bHybrid");
        const bOceans = document.getElementById("bOceans");
        const bTerrain = document.getElementById("bTerrain");
        let basemapButton = bTopoVector;
        let nextBasemapButton = bHybrid;
        basemapButton.disabled = true;
        nextBasemapButton.disabled = true;
        const nextBasemapChange = (newNextBasemap, newNextBasemapButton) => {
            nextBasemap = newNextBasemap;
            toggle.nextBasemap = nextBasemap;
            nextBasemapButton.disabled = false;
            nextBasemapButton = newNextBasemapButton;
            nextBasemapButton.disabled = true;
        };
        bTopoVector.addEventListener("click", () => nextBasemapChange("topo-vector", bTopoVector));
        bHybrid.addEventListener("click", () => nextBasemapChange("hybrid", bHybrid));
        bOceans.addEventListener("click", () => nextBasemapChange("oceans", bOceans));
        bTerrain.addEventListener("click", () => nextBasemapChange("terrain", bTerrain));
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        Next Basemap:
        <button id="bTopoVector">Topo Vector</button>
        <button id="bHybrid">Hybrid</button>
        <button id="bOceans">Oceans</button>
        <button id="bTerrain">Terrain</button>
    </div>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Cabesuon!  Do you know if there is any way to modify it instead of having to remove/recreate the toggle widget every time from the view? (view.ui.remove(toggle);)

Comment: I have updated the answer, it was much more simple, sorry.

Comment: Thank You Cabesuon!  I have marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi Cabesuon, I ran into another issue with setting font dynamically.  By any chance would you know how to resolve this issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76581666

Answer (score 0):

BasemapToggle widget is only able to change between 2 basemaps. It is not clear from your example if you are trying to change to a third map or not. If you want to be able to use more than 2 basemaps I would recommend using

**[BasemapGallery](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-BasemapGallery.html)**

```
const basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
   view: view,
   source: [Basemap.fromId("topo-vector"), Basemap.fromId("hybrid")] 
// Add as many basemaps in this list as you want
});
```

Comment: Thank you Martin!  I only need two maps, but I need to change the second map to a new value.  (Ex. Modify activeBasemap)

Comment: No problem. I am not sure if I understand your problem. Do you want to change the second map in runtime? Please elaborate :) 

If your problem is that you want to toggle between the maps please let me know and I will show you how its done.

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry I did not explain it in detail.  You are absolutely correct, I would like to change the second map in runtime.