# Set font size using an if statement condition for FeatureLayer labelingInfo using arcgis javascript api 4.x

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am trying to set font size using an if statement condition for FeatureLayer labelingInfo using arcgis javascript api 4.x.

This is the feature layer:

```
    const myLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        title: "My Layer",
        objectIdField: "ObjectID",
        geometryType: "point",
        source: myFeatures,
        showLabels: true,
        labelingInfo: myLabelingInfo,
        outFields : ['*']
    });
```

This is the labelinginfo object:

```
    var myLabelingInfo = [
        {
            symbol: {
                type: "text",
                color: "white",
                font: {
                    family: "Arial",
                    size: "IIf($feature.customer.length == 1, 12, 8);", // 12,
                    weight: "bold",
                    decoration: "none"
                }
            }
        }
    ];
```

As you can see, I tried setting the font size with an if statement:

```
size: "IIf($feature.customer.length == 1, 12, 8);", // 12,
```

But that does not work.  If I set it hard-coded is the only way it works:

```
size: 12,
```

My question is, how can I dynamically/programmatically change the font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving what you want is to have as many `LabelClass` as symbols you need, and then using the property `where` to apply correctly to each feature.

In this case, you will have two `LabelClass`, one for each font size,

```
const createLabelSymbol = (fontSize) => ({
    symbol: {
        type: "text",
        color: "white",
        font: {
            family: "Arial",
            size: fontSize,
            weight: "bold",
            decoration: "none"
        }
    }
});

const myLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    title: "My Layer",
    objectIdField: "ObjectID",
    geometryType: "point",
    source: myFeatures,
    showLabels: true,
    labelingInfo: [
        {
            labelExpressionInfo: {expression: "EXPRESSION"},
            symbol: createLabelSymbol(12),
            where: "CONDITION"
        },
        {
            labelExpressionInfo: {expression: "EXPRESSION"},
            symbol: createLabelSymbol(8),
            where: "NOT CONDITION"
        }
    ],
    outFields : ['*']
});
```

Where *EXPRESSION* is an arcade label expression, and *CONDITION* is an sql where expression.
Take a look at the example I put for you base on one of ESRI,

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>
      Add labels to a FeatureLayer | Sample | ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript
      4.27
    </title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.27/"></script>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/WebMap",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
      ], (WebMap, MapView, FeatureLayer) => {
        const labelClassOpen = {
          // autocasts as new LabelClass()
          symbol: {
            type: "text", // autocasts as new TextSymbol()
            color: "green",
            backgroundColor: [213, 184, 255, 0.75],
            borderLineColor: "green",
            borderLineSize: 1,
            yoffset: 5,
            font: {
              // autocast as new Font()
              family: "Playfair Display",
              size: 12,
              weight: "bold"
            }
          },
          labelPlacement: "above-center",
          labelExpressionInfo: {
            expression: "$feature.MARKER_ACTIVITY"
          },
          where: "OPENSTATUS='open'"
        };
        const labelClassOther = {
          // autocasts as new LabelClass()
          symbol: {
            type: "text", // autocasts as new TextSymbol()
            color: "grey",
            backgroundColor: [213, 184, 255, 0.75],
            borderLineColor: "grey",
            borderLineSize: 1,
            yoffset: 5,
            font: {
              // autocast as new Font()
              family: "Playfair Display",
              size: 8,
              weight: "bold"
            }
          },
          labelPlacement: "above-center",
          labelExpressionInfo: {
            expression: "$feature.MARKER_ACTIVITY"
          },
          where: "NOT OPENSTATUS='open'"
        }

        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: new WebMap({
            portalItem: {
              // autocasts as new PortalItem
              id: "372b7caa8fe340b0a6300df93ef18a7e"
            },
            layers: [
              new FeatureLayer({
                portalItem: {
                  // autocasts as new PortalItem
                  id: "6012738cd1c74582a5f98ea30ae9876f"
                },
                labelingInfo: [labelClassOpen, labelClassOther],
                renderer: {
                  type: "simple", // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
                  symbol: {
                    type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
                    color: "rgba(0,100,0,0.6)",
                    size: 3,
                    outline: {
                      color: [0, 0, 0, 0.1],
                      width: 0.5
                    }
                  }
                }
              })
            ]
          }),
          center: [-116.925, 34.2501],
          zoom: 12
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked perfect!!  Thank you Cabesuon, I was able to have different font sizes now depending on where criteria.